# Scala3/Dotty explicit nulls Scala2 interop

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

I was looking at Dotty documentation and I have a doubt about [Explicit Nulls](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/explicit-nulls.html)

It seems that it will work with Java interoperability, but what about Scala 2.x libraries?
Will types be `String|Null` for scala function returning a `String` or will it assume we will not have a null for them?

Comment: All Java libraries will implicitly all return `T | Null`. All Scala libraries will assume not null.